# ExtJS change the height of the loadmask

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I have this loadmask over a grid which I want to change the height of.

I have managed to change the height using

```
var loadMask = grid.view.loadMask;
loadMask .setHeight(maskHeigtht);
```

but that just changes the message height. I want the bluie mask at the back to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the overall purpose of this? The loadmask can be attached to any Ext.Element, so you can potentially attach it to a different sized element and mask that?

Comment: Well I have a panel with a grid in it and the mask covers the greed when the store is loading but it also extends further down (off the page) which creates a scroll bar momentarily while the mask is active. I want to reduce the height so it's not out of the scope of the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would typically apply the mask to the element you wanted to mask explicitly. Often I use code like this to mask a grid.

```
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getEl(); //note the use of getEl() to get the grids containing element

    grid.mask("Loading data...");

    Ext.getStore('myStore').load({
        callback: function () {             
            grid.unmask();
        }
    });
```

The code above would mask the grid whilst a store loads and then unmask it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks very much! Using your example I added: 
        viewConfig: {
            loadMask: false
        }
to the panel then this is my store listener: 
listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store, operation, options){
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('programList').getEl(); 
            grid.mask("Loading data...");

        },
        load: function() {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('programList').getEl();
            grid.unmask();
        }
    }
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yeah, there are many many ways you can put on a remove the masks, in general though, as you've done, find the element you want, find two sensible events to add and remove the mask and go from there. Glad it helped